# How do I initialize Vue2Vis on a laptop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vis.js

I cloned Vue2Vis and executed the command
`npm install --save @vue2vis/graph2d vis-data moment`
as stipulated in the `packages/graph2d/README.md` file. Here is the result:

```
npm install --save @vue2vis/graph2d vis-data moment
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @vue2vis/graph2d@1.0.1-alpha.0
npm ERR! Found: uuid@7.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/uuid
npm ERR!   dev uuid@"^7.0.0" from @vue2vis/graph2d@1.0.1-alpha.0
npm ERR!   packages/graph2d
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer uuid@"^3.4.0" from vis-timeline@7.3.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vis-timeline
npm ERR!   vis-timeline@"^7.3.4" from @vue2vis/graph2d@1.0.1-alpha.0
npm ERR!   packages/graph2d
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/erlebach/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/erlebach/.npm/_logs/2021-06-21T22_11_11_109Z-debug.log
```

I thought this procedure was foolproof! :-) Does anybody have any insight to help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `vis-data`'s latest release (7.x) is now incompatible with `graph2d`. The other errors in your stacktrace seem related to `vis-data` 7.

Specifying `vis-data@^6.3.0` in the installation worked without errors:

```sh
$ npm install --save @vue2vis/graph2d vis-data@^6.3.0 moment

added 15 packages, and audited 16 packages in 4s

3 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Comment: I was hopeful. But I got the followint errors:

Comment: your suggestion did not work. Unfortunately, the message received is longer than allowed by 3000 characters.

Comment: That indicates a deeper problem with your dependencies. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: Yes,I will. You mean on GitHub? I had never heard the term. I will do this later this morning..

Comment: Yes, GitHub is ideal for me.